# Reorder columns in a random order

Tags: java

I am trying to randomly reorder the columns of my 2d array, so far it isn't working properly. If anyone could help show me what i need to change in order to get it working i would be very grateful. The columns are currently in the order of 1 to 6 but I am trying to randomize the order.

```
package assignment8;

/**
 *
 * @author kozit015
 */
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class Assignment8 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

}public static void jackknife(){
    int[]a= {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0};
    int[]b= {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    int[]c= {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int[]d= {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
    int[] newArray = new int[a.length + b.length + c.length]; 
    System.arrayCopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, a.length);
    System.arrayCopy(b, 0, newArray, a.length, b.length);
    System.arrayCopy(c, 0, newArray, a.length + b.length, c.length);

    shuffleArray(arrayCopy);
     for (int i = 0; i < arrayCopy.length; i++)
{
     System.out.print(arrayCopy[i] + " ");
}


    int newArray2d[][] = new int[5][4]; 
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        newArray2d[i][j] = array1d[(j*10) + i]; 



}static void shuffleArray(int[] ar){

    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);

      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
   }
```

}
    }

Comment: Why not go through a `List` and use `Collections.shuffle()`?

Comment: This might be a school work or something which he can't use list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better if you do your array as a **2D array**, then you can shuffle it **with a loop**.

```
int[][] myArray = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
```

You can shuffle with a loop instead of shuffling it manually after you have a 2D array.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

//shuffle rows/cols
for(int x=0; x<myArray.length; x++)
{
   int idx = rnd.nextInt(myArray.length);
   if(idx != x){
       int[] temp = myArray[x];
       myArray[x] = myArray[idx];
       myArray[idx] = temp;
   }
}
```

**Test of codes:**

```
for(int x=0; x<myArray.length; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<myArray[0].length; y++)
        System.out.print(myArray[x][y]);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

**output:**

```
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 2 3
```

Comment: You could optimize and `continue` if the random generated index is equal to `x`

Comment: @fge initially I only wanted to give a simple and short solution so it is easier for OP to understand. Anyway, I've added that condition.

Comment: That's OK ;) I'd have written `if idx == x continue;` instead but that's a matter of preferences, of course -- ultimately the JIT will compile that to the same code

Comment: @fge Yes, I know what's on your mind. But I wanted some variations. So I wrote that ;)